# ODK OpenDataKit - Dynamically Fill in Select Box Options?

Tags: json, xml, odk

We are starting with OpenDataKit and would like to create a select box / spinner which we can dynamically update without having to generate and upload a new XML file.

Is it possible to link a select box to an XML or JSON feed, and use that feed to generate the options in the select box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers of Open Data Kit (ODK).

While creating this smarter select one is possible in Android, there is a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/opendatakit/issues/detail?id=289) in JavaROSA (the library that powers ODK's form processing) that will likely result in data loss. In the case of a select1, the value you save will be discarded silently the next time you reload the saved instance.

Fixing this problem in JavaROSA is a good first step.

Comment: Can someone say what the status of this is?